# как создать свои стрелки для flexslider 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

У меня на сайте стоит flexslider2. Мне не нравится место где расположены стрелки. Я хочу чтобы они были под слайдером и имели другую иконку. Но я никак не пойму, что нужно для этого сделать.

Comment: Стрелки где?  Слайдер какой? можно пожалуйста код или фото хотя бы

Comment: слайдер - flexslider2 (в название указано)

Comment: а стрелки, такие же, какие и во всех flexslider'ах

Comment: возьми просто переопредели стили в своих, если не будут поддаваться пиши !important; . А по поводу их вида пререопредели .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
    content: '\f002';
} Замени контент у before элемента.

Comment: Здравствуйте. **1).** Считаю, что flexslider-2 в настоящее время использовать не стоит, так как у него нет свайпа(нельзя потянуть за сам слайд, а только кнопки навигации). В общем есть более удачные бесплатные слайдеры, рекомендую **Swiper**, так как он работает без jQuery. **2).** `!important;` как вам здесь советуют выше, конечно в стилях лучше не использовать.

Comment: Спасибо! Рассмотрю, предложенный вами swiper